RAM-optimized filter for integer-keyed LSM tree
I’m designing an LSM tree where the keys are integers within a known range, say [0, 8 million]. Normally an LSM tree would use Bloom filters for each SSTable to help a reader identify SSTables that might contain the key they’re looking for.
However, when I calculate ideal Bloom filter parameters, it’s telling me the optimal size is 3-10 MiB depending on the false positive rate I choose. For only 8 million possible keys I can store a dense bitfield in 1MiB, so it makes no sense to store a larger data structure that’s also less exact. The downside of the dense bitfield is that it doesn’t scale down for higher (sparser) levels of the LSM tree — it’s always 1MiB.
What’s the most space efficient data structure to do what I want? Bonus points if it supports range queries (max requested range size can be bounded to say 100 keys - no large or open ranges).
